# Nginx error 400 through Cloudflare

Tags: domains, web-hosting, nginx, cloudflare

I recently added my site to Cloudflare and all of my subdomains like portainer and my file server are working however my main domain that points to my Nginx server returns "error 400 bad request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

I am using caddy to reverse proxy with this config

```
georgenet.uk:443 {
tls internal
reverse_proxy 192.168.0.50:444
}

georgenet.uk:80 {
tls internal
reverse_proxy 192.168.0.50:81
}
```

and my Nginx server is using this config

```
server {
    listen 81;
    listen [::]:81;
    server_name georgenet.uk www.georgenet.uk;
    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 444 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:444 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    server_name georgenet.uk www.georgenet.uk;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I have already tried `ssl off` and `ssl on` like many solutions have suggested however I keep getting this error, is it something to do with caddy redirecting the default ports to 81 and 444 as this was working before I started using Cloudflare.

Answer (score 2):

Ports 81 and 444 are not among the [ports supported by Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/network-ports/). To get Cloudflare to work you need to choose from among the following supported ports:

> #### HTTP ports supported by Cloudflare
>
> - 80
> - 8080
> - 8880
> - 2052
> - 2082
> - 2086
> - 2095
>
> #### HTTPS ports supported by Cloudflare
>
> - 443
> - 2053
> - 2083
> - 2087
> - 2096
> - 8443

Comment: the ports 81 and 444 are only used inside my network, the reverse proxy (caddy) translates them from 81 and 444 to 80 and 443 when traffic is sent back to and from cloudflare. So cloudflare should only see traffic on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: Can you include your reverse proxy configuration. My guess is something's wrong with that then.

Comment: The first section of code in my post is the caddy configuration for the website, this method was working for when I was using Lets encrypt before I changed to cloudflare. The same config is used for my other services such as portainer and filebrowser where I point the 80 and 443 port to the docker containers.

Comment: Why do you have `tls internal` on the port 80 configuration in caddy?  That could be part of the problem.

Comment: I used this method to configure my caddy [link](https://rux.vc/2021.02/https-with-cloudflare-and-caddy/)

Comment: Based on what they are doing I would try using just `georgenet.uk {
tls internal
reverse_proxy 192.168.0.50:81
}` for your caddy configuration

Comment: I tried the config you suggested however I still get the same error, I also tried adding http://georgenet.uk and https://georgenet.uk instead of having the ports however I am still getting the same error

Comment: As a next step you should use the command line tool like curl to test your origin server on all of its ports. If you tell your origin server IP address I can help you with this stuff

Comment: 90.215.148.28   The only ports i have open are 443 and 80, everything goes through caddy and is then redirected to docker ports. Thanks for looking in to this

Comment: The problem is with your origin configuration.  I can confirm that you get the error without involving Cloudflare at all.  `curl --insecure --resolve georgenet.uk:443:90.215.148.28 https://georgenet.uk/` shows "400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port"

Comment: `curl --head --resolve georgenet.uk:80:90.215.148.28 http://georgenet.uk/` is redirecting to HTTPS properly.  It shows  "HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect Location: https://georgenet.uk/"

Comment: You should use those same commands locally to test the docker ports.  eg `curl --insecure --resolve georgenet.uk:444:192.168.0.50 https://georgenet.uk:444/`

Comment: I ended up giving up on nginx, not sure what the problem was but I though I would just use caddy as the web server since it has that functionality and it seems pointless to redirect it to another port when it can serve the files itself.

Thanks for your help